# Objective-c: Questions about self = [super init]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen `self = [super init]` in init methods. I don't understand why. Wouldn't `[super init]` return the superclass? And if we point `self = [super init]`, are we not getting `self = superclass`? 
Here's an example code fragment

```
- (id)init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        creationDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope someone can clarify this for me. Thank you.

Comment: Search for "isa pointer".

Comment: It is quite nicely explained here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming that `MyClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass`, the following happens when
you call

```
MyClass *mc = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

1. `[MyClass alloc]` allocates an instance of `MyClass`.
2. The `init` message is sent to this instance to complete the initialization process.
   In that method, `self` (which is a hidden argument to all Objective-C methods) is
   the allocated instance from step 1.
3. `[super init]` calls the *superclass implementation* of `init` with the same (hidden)
   `self` argument.
   (This might be the point that you understood wrongly.)
4. In the `init` method of `BaseClass`, `self` is still the *same instance* of `MyClass`.
   This superclass init method can now either

   - Do the base initialization of `self` and return `self`, or
   - Discard `self` and allocate/initialize and return a different object.
5. Back in the `init` method of `MyClass`: `self = [super init]` is now either

   - The `MyClass` object that was allocated in step 1, or
   - Something different. (That's why one should check and use this return value.)
6. The initialization is completed (using the `self` returned by the superclass init).

---

So, if I understood your question correctly, the main point is that

```
[super init]
```

calls the superclass implementation of `init` with the `self` argument,
which is a `MyClass` object, not a `BaseClass` object.

Comment: In step 4, would the "different object" be anything other than `nil`?

Answer (score 6):

As you have Question `self = [super init]` in the if Condition suggest a specific meaning.

First of all `[super init]` gives the initialization of the superclass of the existing class which is in use currently. Using `[super init]` gives the super class initialization which shows that object exist of the class.

Now when you use `self = [super init]` that means you are assigning the class to the self for the further utilization of the same class.

And at the end you put it in if condition as `if(self = [super init])` this means you are checking whether the object of the class exist of not to prevent the foul behavior of the application.

I think it is clear now!!!

Answer (score 4):

@MartinR has a very good answer. But do you ever wonder why "[super init] calls the superclass implementation of init with the same (hidden) self argument. (This might be the point that you understood wrongly.)" works in his 3rd point ?

Here is the excerpt from Big Nerd Ranch guide 3rd edition, chapter 2 Objective C that clarifies this point

> “How does super work? Usually when you send a message to an object,
>   the search for a method of that name starts in the object’s class. If
>   there is no such method, the search continues in the superclass of the
>   object. The search will continue up the inheritance hierarchy until a
>   suitable method is found. (If it gets to the top of the hierarchy and
>   no method is found, an exception is thrown.)”
>
> “When you send a message to super, you are sending a message to **self**,
>   but the search for the method **skips** the object’s class and starts at
>   the **superclass**.”

This code shows how iOS Runtime performs this task

```
objc_msgSendSuper(self, @selector(init));
```

Answer (score 2):

Every method that you declare has two hidden parameters: self and _cmd.

The following method:

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString;
```

is converted by the compiler to the following function call:

```
id initWithString(id self, SEL _cmd, NSString *aString);
```

see this link for more:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html

Answer (score 2):

Self = [super init];

According to JAVA, **this** mean a pointer to instance itself so object can message itself.

Same meainng of **Self** here in objective C,

According to JAVA, **Super** mean that allow to access base or parent class

Same meainng of **Super** here in objective C,

Now **init** instance to to complete the initialization process.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html):

Because an init... method might return nil or an object other than the one explicitly allocated, it is dangerous to use the instance returned by alloc or allocWithZone: instead of the one returned by the initializer. Consider the following code:

```
id myObject = [MyClass alloc];
[myObject init];
[myObject doSomething];
```

The init method in the example above could have returned nil or could have substituted a different object. Because you can send a message to nil without raising an exception, nothing would happen in the former case except (perhaps) a debugging headache. But you should always rely on the initialized instance instead of the “raw” just-allocated one. Therefore, you should nest the allocation message inside the initialization message and test the object returned from the initializer before proceeding.

```
id myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
if ( myObject ) {
    [myObject doSomething];
} else {
    // error recovery... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think of it as, init'ing all the supers variables etc, then you get to init your extended classes variables before it is returned.

Answer (score 1):

`[super init]` is the same as [**self** superclass_variant_of_init]

If you want to send a message to superclass, there is another approach (without using runtime library):

```
[[self superclass] init];
```