# adding object to NSMutableArray but get nil instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, calculator

I'm writing a calculator app in objective-c for iOS. My goal at this point is to add the digit that the user presses onto an NSMutableArray acting as a LIFO stack so I can later perform calculations on them by popping them off the stack. I inserted a breakpoint at the end of the '(IBAction)operationPressed' method and the debugger shows that my NSMutableArray aka programStack has the value 'nil'. Could anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

programStack is synthesized in my .m file and declared as nonatomic, strong in my .h file

Let me know if there is more code that I should be showing

```
     //All code from my .h file
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        /*
        @interface ViewController : UIViewController


        @end
        */

        @interface Compute : NSObject
        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *programStack;

        -(void)pushOperand:(double)operand;
        -(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;
        -(double)popOperand;
        @end

        @interface Calculator : UIViewController
        @property (nonatomic, strong) Compute *comp;
        @property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *operationUserHasPressed;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *display;
        @property double operand;   //I added this

        -(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
        -(IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
        -(IBAction)equalToSignPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
        @end

        //Some code from my .m file
        #import "ViewController.h"
        @interface Compute ()

        @end

        @implementation Compute

        @synthesize programStack;

        -(void)pushOperand:(double)operand {
            [self.programStack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
        }
        @end
        @interface Calculator ()

        @end

        @implementation Calculator

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            //An error comes up
            self.programStack = [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];
        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @synthesize display;
        @synthesize operationUserHasPressed;
        @synthesize comp;

        -(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

            //To obtain the number entered by the user
            NSString *numberEntered = sender.currentTitle;

            //Display number entered by the user
            display.text = numberEntered;

            if ([sender.currentTitle  isEqual: @"1"]) {
                self.operand = 1.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"2"]) {
                self.operand = 2.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"3"]) {
                self.operand = 3.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"4"]) {
                self.operand = 4.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"5"]) {
                self.operand = 5.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"6"]) {
                self.operand = 6.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"7"]) {
                self.operand = 7.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"8"]) {
                self.operand = 8.00;
            } else if ([sender.currentTitle isEqual:@"9"]) {
                self.operand = 9.00;
            }
        }

        -(IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

            //To obtain the operation entered by the user
            self.operationUserHasPressed = sender.currentTitle;

            [self.comp pushOperand: self.operand];
        }   //Place breakpoint here

        -(IBAction)equalToSignPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

            //To obtain the result of the computation
            double result = 0;
            [self.comp pushOperand: self.operand];
            result = [self.comp performOperation:self.operationUserHasPressed];

        }
        @end
```

Comment: You should add you code to your question rather than screen shots.  Have you actually allocated and initialised your NSMutableArray?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do some minor changes with your code.
First of all replace your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method with following :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Allocation and Initialization of your Compute Class
    comp = [[Compute alloc] init];
}
```

And add one more method in your Compute.m File:

```
- (id)init {
    if(self == [super init]) {
        self.programStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: mehulsojitra, teos mentioned it being init in the inner brackets and alloc on the outer ones. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Would you be able to answer my question above?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you can't use `self.programStack = [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];`. I tried it and app crash due to that, so use code as i said above.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Would you mind explaining the code to me? or at least the [super viewDidLoad] and the condition in the if statement?

Comment: To use Compute class you needs to allocate and initialize them before you use it. And next method - (id)init called when you call comp = [[Compute alloc] init]; Initialize all your object inside this method that you want like array allocation.

Comment: For more detail you can refer this link: [super init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693023/objective-c-questions-about-self-super-init)

Answer (score 0):

You mention that 'programStack' is synthesized, but it only means that its public getter/setter will be generated. It will not be created for you.
As Paulw11 noted in his comment, I believe you probably miss the allocation.

It would usually take place in the -(id)init or the -(void)viewDidLoad of your UIViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.programStack = @[].mutableCopy; // or [[NSMutableArray init] alloc];
}
```

Comment: So I am confused on how many UIViewControllers you can have. When I started up the project I got the default ViewController.m and .h already set up. But my professor gave us code to start out with and she defined the Calculator class to be the UIViewController. I tried initializing programStack in the default UIController under -(void)viewDidLoad but I got an error so I commented the ViewController out in my .h file and didn't include the implementation in my .m portion above. Instead I copied the those methods into the Calculator UIViewController. Am I wrong here?

Comment: If this solves your initial problem, please consider marking it as resolved. Concerning your other question, you can have any number of viewControllers in an app. If you have issues figuring out how they behave, I suggest you post another (new) question.

Comment: how do mark this question as resolved? Sorry Im new to using this site

Comment: I did not see you accepted mehulsojitra's answer. Nothing more to do here.